# ESP8266 BearSSL performance

Tags: esp8266

I am playing with a minimal https server on an ESP01S, using `BearSSL::ESP8266WebServerSecure`.

- With 2048bit RSA keys it takes ~5 seconds to serve a "hello" request.
- Using 256bit EC keys it takes ~2 seconds.

I wonder whether it is possible to make key exchange faster without giving up on reasonable security level.

I am struggling with trying to set `ec_all_m15` implementation (see [Key Exchange](https://www.bearssl.org/support.html#key-exchange)) to make it faster without any luck - I have actually no idea how to do it properly .

I tried something like

```
...
BearSSL::X509List *cert = new BearSSL::X509List(serverCert.c_str());
BearSSL::PrivateKey *key = new BearSSL::PrivateKey(serverKey.c_str());
server.setECCert(cert, BR_KEYTYPE_EC, key);
server.begin();
br_ssl_server_context sc;
br_ssl_server_init_full_ec(&sc, cert->getX509Certs(), 1, BR_KEYTYPE_EC, key->getEC());
br_ssl_engine_set_ec(&sc.eng, &br_ec_all_m15);
br_ssl_server_reset(&sc);
```

Could someone help pls?

Comment: it always going to be slow. what have you tried?

Comment: @dandavis I have added to the post.